# SQL: counting columns that can have null values

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I have a query that retrieves names of tables and count of columns in each of them.

```
SELECT Table_Schema, Table_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM Information_Schema.Columns
GROUP BY Table_Schema, Table_Name
HAVING Table_Schema = 'schema';
```

How can I add to this query **count of columns that CAN store NULL values**?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `is_nullable` column:

```
SELECT Table_Schema, Table_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE is_nullable = 'YES'
GROUP BY Table_Schema, Table_Name
HAVING Table_Schema = 'schema';
```

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) on `information_schema.columns` describes the table in full detail, including other columns that might be of interest.

EDIT:

If you want to add the information to the existing query, just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Table_Schema, Table_Name, COUNT(*), SUM( (is_nullable = 'YES')::int ) as nullable_clumns
FROM Information_Schema.Columns
GROUP BY Table_Schema, Table_Name
HAVING Table_Schema = 'schema';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `FILTER` condition to the aggregate function to only count the rows where the condition is met:

```
SELECT table_Schema,
       table_Name,
       count(*) AS total_columns,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE is_nullable = 'YES') AS nullable_columns
FROM information_schema.columns
GROUP BY table_Schema, table_Name
HAVING table_schema = 'schema';
```

Comment: Thanks, this modification was exactly what I was looking for :)